# How to implement the abstract method in interface?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to implement an abstract method in an interface. Given this interface:

```
public interface Analysis
{
    public double getAverage();
}
```

To implement the abstract method, do I just declare the method as abstract?

```
public abstract double getAverage();  ??
```

or declare the interface as abstract?

```
    public abstract interface Analysis
   {
      public double getAverage();
    }
```

Or are other things needed?

I have a class that implements the interface called `Marks`:

```
   public class Marks implements Analyzable
{    some other code
     constructor
     mutators
     accessor
     public double getAverage();
}
```

So, my main problem is How to implement the abstract method in interface?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You have an interface, and you have a class that implements that interface.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

To make an abstract class implementing the interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractAnalysis implements Analysis {
    public abstract double getAverage();
}
```

To make a concrete class implementing the interface:

```
public class MyAnalysis implements Analysis {
    public double getAverage() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Or, to make a concrete class extending the abstract class and thereby implementing the interface:

```
public class MyAnalysis extends AbstractAnalysis {
    public double getAverage() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: In the abstract class `AbstractAnalysis` you don't need to write the line `public abstract double getAverage();` - it is redundant.

Comment: Then How to implement the abstract method in interface?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply declare your abstract class to implement `Analysis`, without implementing `getAverage()` or declaring it in your abstract class, concrete subclasses of your abstract class will be required to provide an implementation of that method.

Answer (score 1):

Every method in an interface will be abstract. This is one of the specifications in Java.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html